# Apache Virtual Host not working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I've been using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) to set up an Apache virtual host on my Ubuntu pc. I've created a `no-ip domain` which I will be using as the hostname of my virtual host. I've followed every step of the tutorial but it doesn't work. Here's the virtual host file and it's named `crm2plus.ddns.net.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@crm2plus.ddns.net
        ServerName  crm2plus.ddns.net
        ServerAlias crm2plus.ddns.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/crm2plus.ddns.net/public_html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I've also added the ip and domain name pair to my local hosts file and here's how it looks:

```
23.253.21.201   shhasan.ddns.net
127.0.1.1       Ubuntu-Dev
127.0.0.1       localhost
99.250.71.177   crm2plus.ddns.net

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

When I navigate to `crm2plus.ddns.net` through chrome I get the `web page not available page`. `shhasan.ddns.net` is working fine. When I type `ssh-keygen -H -F crm2plus.ddns.net` into the terminal nothing shows up but when I type `ssh-keygen -H -F shhasan.ddns.net` this is what shows up:

```
# Host shhasan.ddns.net found: line 14 type RSA
```

followed by the RSA key.

I've also looked at the Apache error and access logs. The error logs have a lot of repetition of such line of code:

```
[Fri Nov 14 17:44:50.304782 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21927] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 14 17:44:50.304801 2014] [core:notice] [pid 21927] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Nov 14 17:44:54.979832 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21927] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

I searched for `caught SIGTERM, shutting down` and I found that this was part of normal operation. I have no idea of where I'm going wrong. It had worked previously for `shhasan.ddns.net` but it doesn't work for `crm2plus.ddns.net`.

All help and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

---

Update:

`developer@Ubuntu-Dev:/etc/apache2$ ls
apache2.conf   apache2.conf.dpkg-dist  conf-enabled  httpd.conf   magic           mods-enabled  ports.conf~      sites-enabled
apache2.conf~  conf-available          envvars       httpd.conf~  mods-available  ports.conf    sites-available`

`developer@Ubuntu-Dev:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ ls
000-default.conf  000-default.conf~  000-default.conf.dpkg-dist  crm2plus.ddns.net.conf  crm2plus.ddns.net.conf~  default.save  default-ssl.conf  shhasan.ddns.net.conf`

`developer@Ubuntu-Dev:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ ls
crm2plus.ddns.net.conf  shhasan.ddns.net.conf`

`apache2.conf` shortened version:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
ServerName localhost

Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
#    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Comment: Did you enable the site?

Comment: Yes I have enabled it. It was part of the tutorial.

Comment: is `apache` running? run `/etc/init.d/apache2 status` to see if its started or not.

Comment: @PeteyT ` /etc/init.d/apache2 status` -->
` * apache2 is running`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the Apache2.4 syntax for access control in the Virtual Host definition file, as you are using Apache2.4, then if you have not activated `mod_access_compat.so` it should work or if you have you can deactivate it.

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I must admit I prefer to add the access control for a Virtual Host within the VH definition itself. Then you know with just a look whats actually going on. So you might consider doing it this way.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@crm2plus.ddns.net
    ServerName  crm2plus.ddns.net
    ServerAlias www.crm2plus.ddns.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/crm2plus.ddns.net/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/crm2plus.ddns.net/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also you should be careful when messing with this parameter in the httpd.conf file

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
#    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

This controls Apache's access to the root folder, and of course you would not want to allow Apache or a hacker on your Apache access to the universe would you.

So I suggest you set this back to

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Using the Apache2.4 syntax again of course.

---

Update: A slightly edited version of the above VH definition worked for `crm2plus.ddns.net`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName crm2plus.ddns.net
        ServerAlias crm2plus.ddns.net
    ServerRoot /var/www/crm2plus.ddns.net/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/crm2plus.ddns.net/public_html

    <Directory "/var/www/crm2plus.ddns.net/public_html">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>


    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/crm2plus.ddns.net_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/crm2plus.ddns.net_access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `mod_access_compat` how do I disable it ?

Comment: You dont have to, its just to provide compatibility for old 2.2 syntax. Did any of this help?

Comment: you do `sudo a2dismod mod_access_compat`.

Comment: `sudo a2dismod mod_access_compat` --> `ERROR: Module mod_access_compat does not exist!`

Comment: Then dont worry about it. Using the 2.4 syntax should have fixed your problem

Answer (score 1):

Check your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file. On my Ubuntu 14.04LTS I have to change line:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

to:

```
hosts:          dns files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]
```

In order to make Virtual Hosts work.